# Use whatsapp business cloud api to send messages to groups you are listed in

Tags: whatsapp

We are using the official whatsapp business cloud api (with Make).

We are wondering if there is any chance we can send messages to groups we are list in?

I could not found any documentation about it.

Thanks!

Comment: Whatsapp Business Cloud API does not support sending messages in groups.

Comment: Is there any workaround you know?

Comment: No there is no workaround, you can ask this to direct [facebook support](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/contact-support).